# Scrape #shadow-root (open)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, shadow-dom

I'm trying to scrape href tags that are hidden under a #shadow-root (open) on this website: https://iltacon2022.expofp.com/. I'm new to coding and was wondering if someone could help me out.

Here is the code I've been trying to access the #shadow-root (open), but I'm in front of my skies on what to do next.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = "https://iltacon2022.expofp.com/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(6)

root1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div").shadow_root

root2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div//div")

print(root2)

driver.quit()
```

error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div//div"}
```

Desired output:

```
?access-corp
?accruent-inc
?aceds-association-of-certified-e-discovery-specialists
?actionstep
?aderant
etc
etc
etc
```

Comment: I actually responded to this - see your previous question.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire Each and every question on SO doesn't ask for a boiler plate code. Some questions can be conceptual just like OP's previous question, where I feel the boiler plate code in your answer wasn't necessary. In these cases OP is bound to raise the same question again and again just like this and that's a wastage of time and effort and overall doesn't fits the SO standards.